# bash not setting autocd

Tags: bash, shopt

I try to set `autocd` option in bash so I don't have to type `cd src` and can just type `src`. However `shopt -s autocd` gives me:

```
-bash: shopt: autocd: invalid shell option name
```

(Ubuntu 8.04 hardy)

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04 is old and no longer supported. You should upgrade. If you can't, switch to zsh, which had `setopt autocd` not only before Ubuntu existed, but I think even before Linux existed.

Comment: I cant upgrade the system for fear of breaking the application. It is in house, so no worry about security. I will to zsh, but other systems I cant upgrade, so better stick with bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `autocd` option was added in [bash 4.0 (alpha)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges). You should
check your bash version ( `bash --version` or `echo $BASH_VERSION`) it is probably 3.2.

Comment: `bash --version` will work too.

Comment: i have version 3.2.39, I am not sure I can upgrade tho

Comment: I want to compile bash 4.2 on the system should I apply all the patches from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2-patches/ ?

Comment: @user53689 You should use bash from the repository. Create a new question and I will answer with the details.

Comment: I posted question http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103663/53689