# compiling bash 4.2 with patches

Tags: bash, compiling

I want to compile bash 4.2 from source. but http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz is more 2 years old.

Should i apply all the patches from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2-patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the source with `git`  and then compile:

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/bash.git 
cd bash
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

that should get you bash version 4.2.45 (ie 4.2 including patch 45)

`cvs` would be faster but the repository for bash is empty for some reason. `git` clones the whole history 173Mb, with 27Mb real source.

Comment: At some point, the bash git repo changed/moved to http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/; I won't edit the answer as it's the accepted answer from ~7 years ago, but -- just in case anyone else finds this page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is how Bash increments its minor version number.