# why doesn't bash update through yum?

Tags: bash, centos, yum, upgrade

I'm trying to update bash on CentOS 7 - I need at least 4.4 for my project and the default shell on it is 4.2. It's a production server, so I literally just want a new version of bash as the default shell and that's it; I don't want to be messing around too much or updating anything else.

Anyway, running:

```
yum update bash
```

returns

```
No packages marked for update
```

The command:

```
yum repolist all
```

shows that the CentOS 7 updates repo is enabled (not CentOS 7.* base/updates though).

As a result, this command:

```
 yum  --enablerepo=updates update bash
```

does nothing.

I can share my CentOS-Base.repo file, if it helps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you go down the compiling route, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103665/117549  is one starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of distributions like RedHat (and thus CentOS) is that it's stable; it doesn't have the latest version of every software, it has a consistent version.  For CentOS7 the current version is `bash-4.2.46-33.el7`.  RedHat will backport security fixes but may not backport functionality enhancements because they can cause compatibility issues.

If you need a different version then you may need to compile it from source and place it in a non-standard location (e.g. `$HOME/bin/bash`).  Don't overwrite `/bin/bash` because the OS may replace it at any time through `yum update`.

In comparison, RedHat 8 (CentOS8) has bash 4.4, and Debian 10 has bash 5.0

Answer (score 4):

In case the implied question was, how can I update bash to 4.4:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.18.tar.gz
tar xf bash-4.4.18.tar.gz
cd bash-4.4.18/
./configure
make
make install
sh
bash -version
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash 4.2.46 is the current version for CentOS 7 and RHEL 7. Bash 4.4.19 is the current version for CentOS 8 and RHEL 8. BASH 4.4 is not in the repos for CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 which is why `yum` won't update to it.

To get 4.4, you'll have to build it from source in a location other than `/bin` such as `/home/bash`, put the location to the `bash` binary in /etc/shells (as root only if you want to change it for other users), and then use `chsh -s /path/to/new/bash` to change your login shell to Bash 4.4.

If you just want to run scripts with the newer version of bash, after building it, change the shebang in the scripts to:

```
#!/path/to/new/bash
```

And they will run with the newer version.

Comment: I chose the other answer because it gave more reasons to why i couldn't/shouldnt do what i was trying to do. Still, ill be using your solution ```chsh``` as a workaround, thanks!

Comment: @AlexH That's cool. Glad to help.

Comment: @AlexH, what does (t)csh bring that isn't in bash-4.2? Exactly what new/changed functionality are you depending on?

Comment: @vonbrand Im not using that shell, but bash and i want to use this feature - from the bash manual `A variable can be assigned the nameref attribute using the -n option to the declare or local builtin commands `

Comment: @vonbrand, They said `chsh` (command to change your login shell) not the (t)csh shell.